# c++ inheritance, is not a member error

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hello when i trying to compile this i've got errors in `Mysz.cpp`:

```
error C2039: 'inicjatywa' : is not a member of 'Mysz'   
error C2039: 'sila' : is not a member of 'Mysz'

error C2039: 'typ' : is not a member of 'Mysz'

error C2039: 'symbol' : is not a member of 'Mysz'

etc...
```

`Organizm.h`

```
 #include "header.h"

class Swiat;

class Organizm
{
  protected:
    string typ;
    char   symbol;
    int    sila,inicjatywa, x,y;
    Swiat  *ref;

  public:
    Organizm() { symbol = ' '; };
}
```

Zwierze.h

```
#include "Organizm.h"

class Zwierze: public Organizm
{
  public:
    Zwierze() {};

  public:       
    virtual int kolizja(Organizm& org) override
    {
      if(this->typ==org.getTyp()){return roz;}
        else if(this->sila<org.getSila())return win;
       else return loose;       
    };   

    virtual char akcja() override
    {
      char tab[4]={'p','d','g','l'};
      int kierunek=rand() % 4;
      return tab[kierunek];
    };
};
```

Mysz.h

```
#ifndef MYSZ_H
#define MYSZ_H

class Swiat;

class Mysz: public Zwierze
{
  public:
    Mysz (int x,int y,Swiat *swiat);

  public:
    int kolizja(Organizm& org);    
};
#endif
```

Mysz.cpp

```
#include "Mysz.h"
#include "Swiat.h"

Mysz::Mysz(int x,int y,Swiat *swiat)
{
  this->typ="Mysz";
  this->symbol='M';
  this->sila=1;
  this->inicjatywa=6;
  this->x=x;
  this->y=y;
  this->ref=swiat;
};
```

Comment: You can not access these members of `class Organizm` since they are protected. They are in scope only for the immediate next layer of inheritance (e.g. `class Zwierze`).

Comment: But when I've made them public the same error appeared. Is there no way to make them inherit?

Comment: I don't believe the scope is limited to just the immediate inheritance  for public inheritance (note that I am talking about the access specifier for inheritance. E.g `public Zwierze`). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in `Mysz.h` you have not included `Zwierze.h` which is required because of inheritance `public Zwierze`.

I would have expected a compile error with `Zwierze` before the compilation error with the inherited member variables. Did you not get such an error?

Comment: error C2504: 'Zwierze' : base class undefined. It's after these errors

Comment: Sorry its not after its first.

Comment: `#include "Zwierze.h"` and see if it fixes the errors.